# Can't plot my LineChart from my list of Data

Tags: android, firebase, mpandroidchart

Heres the code for displaying my LineChart
After retrieving a set of data from Firebase, to be used to plot a Line Chart. Somehow I can't display my set of datas to x and y axis as well as the LineChart itself. Please Help. My x axis is "Date: mm/dd/yy" and for my y-axis is Float Data

```
private void displayGraph() {

        //Storage for (String) dates from Firebase: public ArrayList<String> x_axis = new ArrayList<>();
        //public ArrayList<String> y_axis = new ArrayList<>()
        ArrayList<String> xVals = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Entry> yVals = new ArrayList<>();
        int times = 0;

        //date as for X - axis
        for (String xaxis : x_axis) {
            xVals.add(xaxis);
        }

        //values from my y_axis ArrayList to Y - axis
        for (String item : y_axis) {
            yVals.add(new Entry(Float.valueOf(item), times));
            times++;
        }

        //for Y axis
        LineDataSet yValue = new LineDataSet(yVals, "Consumed");

        LineData xydata = new LineData(xVals, yValue);
        linechart.setData(xydata);
        linechart.getXAxis().setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        linechart.invalidate();

    }
```

Comment: https://www.studytutorial.in/android-line-chart-or-line-graph-using-mpandroid-library-tutorial

Comment: Are you doing `Float.valueOf(item)` where the item is in "dd/mm/yy" ?

Comment: Can you show us where did you declare and initialize those variables `x_axis` and `y_axis`? Have you tried checking if they're not null when you call the `displayGraph()` method?